# Mapping много-в-один ASP. Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как в проекте `ASp. net` в `c#` сделать `mapping` адресов? Необходимо, чтобы все `URL` `http://server/some/*` обрабатывались одним `handler`'om (пока это `ashx handler`). Нашел способ сделать мапинг один-в-один, а надо много-в-один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось с помощью Global.asax и пары функций:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{*path}", "~/GisResponser.aspx");
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта. Первый и самый простой - прописать имя обработчика в конец каждого узла.

Т.е. примерно так:

- `http://server/some/myhandler.ashx`
- `http://server/some/..../myhandler.ashx`
- `http://server/some/..../..../myhandler.ashx`

Второй способ - использовать маршрутизацию и для конкретного набора маршрутов прописать свой обработчик.

Comment: В конец каждого узла не вариант, узлов много, а есть какой либо вариант чтобы обработчик получал просто строку URL, а там я уже бы парсил что-куда?

Comment: Можно написать свой HTTP-модуль с регулярными выражениями, но поскульку есть маршрутизация (т.е. это уже сделано за вас), то используйте второй вариант.